# Open MXD from network path

Tags: python

MXD located in below path. I could able to open MXD from Windows explorer from dev box.
I am running the script in development box and accessing mxd from the server
isFile always fails.

`\\server1\d$\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\Unknown_Unknown\poly_test.MapServer\extracted\v101\POLY_TEST.mxd`

```
if os.path.isfile(mxdPath):
    print "Entered into successful"
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
else:
    print "sorry"
```

Comment: supplying code and saying help appreciated is not a real question. please follow the help for pointers on good questions. That being said it looks like permissions to me.

Comment: Since you say that it is `isfile` (from the `os` module) that is failing rather than anything in a GIS site-package like ArcPy I think this is a generic Python question that is better researched/asked at [so].

Answer (score 1):

If you have set,

```
mxdPath = "\\server1\d$\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\Unknown_Unknown\poly_test.MapServer\extracted\v101\POLY_TEST.mxd"
```

Then you should put r before paths in python or escape BackSlashes with another backslash.

option 1:

```
mxdPath = r"\\server1\d$\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\Unknown_Unknown\poly_test.MapServer\extracted\v101\POLY_TEST.mxd"
```

option 2:

```
mxdPath = "\\\\server1\\d$\\arcgisserver\\directories\\arcgissystem\\arcgisinput\\Unknown_Unknown\\poly_test.MapServer\\extracted\\v101\\POLY_TEST.mxd"
```

Comment: Thanks Farid cher. It does not work with both the options.

Comment: It's better to share the error message you get from running the code!